# How to setup VS Code for dart

Tags: dart

I am developing a project with flutter. But I recently wanted to make a pure dart project. So I pressed "Dart: New Project" on visual studio code. It gave me these options to choose from:

- AngularDart Web App,
- Bare-bones Web App,
- Console Application,
- Dart Package,
- StageXL Web app,
- Web server.

I pressed each of them because I didn't know which one was right for just playing around with dart. But after, I could not figure out where to right my dart code. Can anyone please help?

Comment: For just playing around with Dart you probably want a `console-full` project. I don't know VSCode but I think it uses https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stagehand to create new projects.

Comment: I am getting an error when I create a console full application `import 'package:a/a.dart' as a;` What should I do??

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing what the error is.

Comment: The error says this: `[dart] Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:a/a.dart'. [uri_does_not_exist]`

Comment: Do you have a package named `a` with a file `lib/a.dart`. Did you name the project you created `a`?

Comment: I have a project name a.